# Refresh same page without reloading - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to refresh a page without reloading, by refreshing I want to invoke the componentDidMount() function and render the view again.

Below code works when redirecting to a different URL but will not work if we redirect to the same URL.

props.dispatch(push('/sameUrl'));

Comment: When do you want to refresh? At the click of a button?

Comment: after form submission

Comment: Then add the fetch logic to a function and call the function after form submission.

Comment: k but what about invoking a component which calls an api, which happens at the beginning

Comment: You seem to be thinking imperatively. React is more declarative. You need to show some code where you have issue to help you further.

Comment: Think about synchronizing your UI to the data instead of updating your UI in steps, like I do x when y happens. To that end: if you want your component to behave like it did on mount, you have to make your data look the way it did when the component mounted.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem, but i used redux in my project, after i got an element i just updated my page via 'redux-saga/effects' and 'connected-react-router' packages, i set an example (i cut most code and left only needed):

when i sent a request on creating a recipe:

```
import { takeLatest, all, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
import * as constants from './RecipesConstants';
import { recipeAPI } from './../../api/';

function* addRecipe(action) {
  try {
    const recipeResponse = yield call(recipeAPI.addRecipe, action.payload);


    yield put({
      type: constants.ADD_RECIPE_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        ...recipeResponse.data
      }
    });

    yield put(push(`/recipes`)); // <----- here i update my page
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: constants.ADD_RECIPE_FAILED
    });

  }
}
export default function* recipesSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(constants.ADD_RECIPE, addRecipe)
  ])
}
```

hope, it'll help you